# CMakeList - how to use Python and Java with JNI / JVM

Tags: python, java, c++, cmake

I have a small project that combines JNI and Python via pybind. I have it all working in Visual Studio project, however, I am not sure how to write CMakeList file:

I have tried to use `find_package(JNI)`, but it ends with  `Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)`

I have not set JAVA_HOME on OS level, since I want to set it manually in CMakeList because of different Java versions. However, when I set it in CMakeList, `set(JAVA_HOME "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-15.0.1\\")`, it wont work.

Similar problem is with Python, `find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)` is not working and no Python libs are found.

Usually, for libs I use `pkg_check_modules`, but it seems not to be working and I am not able to fing any usable example how to use it with Java or Python.

Comment: According to the documentation for [the `FindJNI` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html) you should be able to specify the java installation by setting the `JAVA_HOME` cmake variable, i.e. passing `-D JAVA_HOME:PATH=/path/to/jdk` should do the trick... The `FindPythonLibs` module is deprecated and should be replaced by e.g. `FindPython3`, which does provide functionality similar to jni via the `Python3_ROOT_DIR` variable

Comment: Java and Python doesn't look as interdependent things, so do not ask about both them in the single question post. "However, when I set it in CMakeList, it wont work." - How **exactly** have you set variable `JAVA_HOME`? Please, add to the question post your attempt (as a code) of setting that variable.